# net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH npm run dev in laravel 9

Tags: laravel, https, ssl-certificate, apache2, vite

my site is running on laravel 9 and works fine until I run the `npm run dev` command. At first there was an error `GET http://127.0.0.1:5173/resources/scss/app.scss net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, I was able to fix it by adding this code to **vite.config.js**:

```
    server: {
        https: true,
        hmr: {
          host: "my ip",
        },
        host: "my ip",
        watch: {
          usePolling: true,
        },
    },
```

And everything started working with `npm run dev` running.

But when I choose to use HTTPS everything works fine until I run the `npm run dev` command. Then a new error occurs: `GET https://my ip:5173/resources/scss/app.scss net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`

My **vite.config.js** looks like this:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel, { refreshPaths } from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        https: true,
        hmr: {
          host: "my ip",
        },
        host: "my ip",
        watch: {
          usePolling: true,
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/scss/app.scss',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: [
                ...refreshPaths,
                'app/Https/Livewire/**',
            ],
        }),
    ],
});
```

My /etc/apache2/sites-available/**domain.com.conf** looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/folder/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/domain.com/folder/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/folder/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/domain.com/folder/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/cloudflare/domain.com.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/cloudflare/domain.com.key
</VirtualHost>
```

how do I run npm run dev so that nothing breaks? Thx.

Comment: Super personal recommendation that will fix this issue, on development machines, NEVER use SSL, unless you work for a bank or anything that requires maximum security... It just creates issues like this one and an overhead of config just for SSL/HTTPS, there is no worth at all

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/9311) might apply to you if you are using vite 3